# What does Flask return when parameters are empty

Tags: python, if-statement, flask, flask-restful, url-parameters

I'm creating a website for ethical hackers where they can search a database of Collections 1-5' data breach. I'm Making this application use URL parameters, to make the application simple I just leave the parameters I'm not using blank ex. `username=&password=pass` but my issue is that sometimes (because it was working before this) returns a random value I can't figure out.

For example, let's say the variable is called `var1`, I make an If statement-making sure that's it's not null so I do

```
if var1 != "":
    pass
```

But there's some weird value going through and the if statement is still running.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried adding multiple values to the if-statement that could also be blank like,
`var1 != "" or var1 != None or var1 != " "`

This is the exact URL I use with postman and it throws a `500 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`

```
http://localhost:6969/search/shordan?ip=&port=&domain=&formated_domain=&asn=&isp=&orginization=&tag=&product=&city=i&country=u&email=&tel=
```

***Note I only added the extra `or !=` statements to the first if loop for testing which didn't work***

And these are my if statements

```py
if ip != "" or ip != None or ip != " ":
    IP = f"ip LIKE '%{ip}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasIP = True
else:
    IP = ""
if port != "" or port != None:
    Port = f"Port LIKE '%{port}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasPort = True
else:
    Port = ""
if domain != "" or domain != None:
    Domain = f"Domain LIKE '%{domain}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasDomain = True
else:
    Domain = ""
if formatedDomain != "" or formatedDomain != None:
    FormatedDomain = f"'FORMATED DOMAIN' LIKE '%{formatedDomain}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasFormatedDomain = True
else:
    formatedDomain = ""
if asn != "" or asn != None:
    print("asn: " + asn)
    Asn = f"asn LIKE '%{asn}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasAsn = True
else:
    Asn = ""
if isp != "" or isp != None:
    ISP = f"ISP LIKE '%{isp}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasISP = True
else:
    ISP = ""
if orginization != "" or orginization != None:
    Orginization = f"ORGANIZATION LIKE '%{orginization}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasOrginization = True
else:
    Orginization = ""
if tag != "" or tag != None:
    Tag = f"tags LIKE '%{tag}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasTag = True
else:
    Tag = ""
if product != "" or product != None:
    print("product: " + product)
    Product = f"product LIKE '%{product}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasProduct = True
else:
    Product = ""
if city != "" or city != None:
    print("city: " + city)
    City = f"city LIKE '%{city}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasCity = True
else:
    City = ""
if country != "" or country != None:
    Country = f"country LIKE '%{country}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasCountry = True
else:
    Country = ""
if email != "" or email != None:
    Email = f"email LIKE '%{email}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasEmail = True
else:
    Email = ""
if tel != "" or tel != None:
    Tel = f"tel LIKE '%{tel}%' "
    andCounter += 1
    hasTel = True
else:
    Tel = ""
```

If it helps I made the if statement make a variable `True` if the if statement runs then i printed that and these are the results

```
Has IP: True
has Port: True
Has Domain: True
Has Formated Domain: True
hasASN: False
hasISP: True
hasOrginization: True
hasTag: True
hasProduct: True
hasCity: True
hasCountry: True
hasEmail: True
hasTel: True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do verify if the param is none by:

```py
@app.route("/test",methods=["GET"]) 
def test():
  emptyvalues = ["", "''", " ", "' '", None, '""', '" "']
  data = request.args
  if "ip" in data and data["ip"] not in emptyvalues:
    hasIP = True
  else:
    hasIP = False
  if "port" in data and data["port"] not in emptyvalues:
    hasPort = True
  else:
    hasPort = False

  print(hasIP, hasPort)
  print(data)
  return 'hello'
```

I used

```
/test?ip=123&port=&domain=&formated_domain=&asn=&isp=&orginization=&tag=&product=&city=i&country=u&email=&tel=
```

Which results to

```py
True
False
ImmutableMultiDict([('ip', '123'), ('port', ''), ('domain', ''), ('formated_domain', ''), ('asn', ''), ('isp', ''), ('orginization', ''), ('tag', ''), ('product', ''), ('city', 'i'), ('country', 'u'), ('email', ''), ('tel', '')])
```

Your code uses "or" instead of "and" that's why the invalid input are passing out as True